# How can I make multiple permalinks in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

The problem is that I have a .htaccess file which redirects users that go to example.com/f89sk3 -> example.com/?s=f89sk3 if it makes any sense.

I want the same thing to happen for people that go to for example:
example.com/p/login -> example.com/p/login

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `example.com/p/login` and `example.com/p/login` are the same... What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your current rule will rewrite `/p/login` to `/index.php?s=p/login` Is there any problem with this?

Comment: @anubhava My current rule only rewrites example.com/codehere to ?s=codehere I still want that to happen, but I also want /p/login to be ?p=login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^p/(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What does this: RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L] do different than this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]?

Comment: Main difference is rule before this rule in my answer. Using `.+` instead of `.*` is a good practice since landing page will automatically load `/index.php`

Comment: Some stuff still isn't working, if I go to /p/adminpanel it loads, but /p/myaccount it doesn't while both pages exist. Can you maybe help me through Skype? Or is that not allowed to be discussed via Stackoverflow?

Comment: You can start a chat session here on SO and interact in realtime.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Back to the subject, so the problem now is that example.com/p/adminpanel works now, but example.com/p/myaccount doesn't work, both are in the same map and ?p=adminpanel works, but ?p=myaccount works as well.

Sorry I can't explain it better.

Comment: I can't make wild guess since I am not in front of your system. Rule is same for both. Hope `/p/myaccount` is not a real directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82532/discussion-between-tom-and-anubhava).